# Is there any way to disable swipe down on Jetpack Compose ModalBottomSheet (Material 3)?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, material-design

I'm trying to disable gestures using Material 3 ModalBottomSheet.  I've seen this question asked, but the accepted answer was to use a different method such as ModalBottomSheetLayout (Material 1). I need to use ModalBottomSheet.

Every other method has a way to disable gestures except this one.

Looking at the implementation, I don't see any options. Even SheetState doesn't have any options.  The reason I want to disable is because I'm showing a LazyColumn, and it "jolts" the bottomsheet when you reach the bottom. Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As of now, there's indeed no way of preventing swipe when using `ModalBottomSheet`. What you can do possibly improving the experience is using `confirmValueChange` from the state:

```kotlin
val state = rememberModalBottomSheetState(
    confirmValueChange = {
        it != SheetValue.Hidden
    }
)

ModalBottomSheet(
    sheetState = state,
    onDismissRequest = { }
) {
    Column {
        LazyColumn {
            items(30) {
                Text(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().height(50.dp).padding(16.dp),
                    text = "Item $it"
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It prevents the sheet from getting to hidden state, this way it still has the swipe down animation, but at least it doesn't close the sheet. But of course, then you would need to have an action in your sheet to close it.

Comment: Thanks, but this is not the desired behavior.